# Calling a view controller class without popping up the view controller itself

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am upgrading my app version, hence needed to reduce two view controllers to one. Hence, I am calling the second view controller skipping the first one. But here I need to call the class of first view controller as there are some important declarations and implementations. How can I call first view controller's class without popping up its view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing.

Why not taking all the initializing code from your first VC (copy-paste your properties, initialization in viewDidLoad etc.) to your second VC ?

Once you are done, get rid of the first VC as it is useless and make your second view controller the root.

A ViewController is meant to be "viewed", I suggest you don't just hide it, that's a really bad architecture.

Comment: thanks @H4Hugo, thats right, but was just curious if there was such an alternative

Comment: @Sam you can make `Superclass: UIViewController`, perform all shared functional in it, and then inherit your view controllers from it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need one view controller at all, then you can delete that View Controller from storyBoard, and also subclass your class as an NSObject class (lets call it `DataProviderClass`) instead of previously( UIViewController) subClass. It isn't a good idea to have a "dummy" view controller in a navigation Stack.

You can use your `DataProviderClass` class as a support file that can provide any data to your Second View Controller. And to perform calculations/methods in this class before launching your second VC, just run these methods in viewdidLoad method, by creating an instance of this NSObject class (`DataProviderClass`) and keeping a reference to it.

When you segue further, you can very easily even transfer the same reference of `DataProviderClass`.